# Handling network outage during transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In a website kiosk, the user was able to add items to his cart, input all necessary information and pressed the submit button.  Displayed to the user was a please wait while order is being processed.

Behind the scenes, the view passed the information to the controller, controller called business logic to card credit card .. the result was successful.  Controller then called business logic to save order in database ... that result was successful.  The next thing the controller was to do was send a redirect back to the view.  The problem is that the user loss connectivity at that time so the web never received the redirect.  When the network connection was restored (talking a few seconds), the web still showed the order, so the user resubmitted it.  So now the user has a duplicate order (different id's though).  How do I go about handling this issue?  My guess is that this is a edge case, at least I am hoping that it is.

Comment: What you're asking about is one of the many problems solved by the field of [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). This is a large school of thought on how architecture should be done so I don't suggest that you switch to it entirely, for the time being something as simple as what Albin suggested would do fine. However, if you're interested in handling difficult scenarios like this you should read up on it and borrow ideas as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a unique transaction id/order id when the form is loaded. Keep track of used transaction id:s, either in memory or in database to make sure you don't submit the same form twice.

You can also disable submit button on the client on first submit to make sure it can't be clicked twice.

Comment: I would specify that the id should be generated on the client, so the client can ask about its status at any time.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, not necessarily, you can generate server side too when you are serving the page and keep a list of the id:s you have generated but not returned.

Comment: Thats true, and technically your session id already identifies the user and you can use it to map to that transaction id. But really for my money just generating the id on the client is so much easier.

Comment: If you generate it server side you can also use it for CSRF protection.

Comment: Thanks for the great responses!  This is kind of what I was thinking but wanted to see how others handled it.  As far as disabling the button, what would be the user experience/recovery if a response/redirect never came back

Comment: @Craig that's a question for the business side of your product. Is it ok to just confirm via email? Maybe you don't need to confirm in the UI at all, maybe you can just say "thank you very much, please be on the look out for an email confirmation in the next hour".